# Using a mif file in Quartus

Tags: fpga, quartus-ii, quartus

I have created an mif file in Quartus and I am working with cyclone 2 Altera. My query is "How can I use this mif file to initialize a variable in my top level design architecture"?
Let me elaborate. My aim is to produce a sine wave using FPGA storing the values in look up tables and accessing it from a VHDL program. I calculated the look up table values myself using MATLAB. I have put them in a mif file. Now I think I should write a program that takes in these LUT values and feed it to the DAC.

For this I am trying to write a vhdl program with a variable that is initialised with my LUT values. I will then assign the values to an output vector variable(should it be a two dimensional array?) and then use the DAC.

I heard there are no direct DACs in cyclone 2?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the memory IP cores to create a memory with initial mif content. You can check the [IP core user guide](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_ram_rom.pdf) for more information.

Another solution is to use VHDL attributes to initialize the content of your variable. You have to be confident that your code is indeed interpreted as a ROM by altera, otherwise the attribute will be ignored. This is the example usage from [altera's documentation](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_ram_init.htm):

```
type mem_t is array(0 to 255) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal ram : mem_t;
attribute ram_init_file : string;
attribute ram_init_file of ram : signal is "my_init_file.mif";
```

A third way, which I prefer, is to initialize the memory in VHDL code, for example:

```
type rom_t is array(0 to 1023) of signed(15 downto 0);

function fill_sin_rom return rom_t is
    variable ret : rom_t;
begin
    for i in ret'range loop
        ret(i) := to_signed(integer((2.0**15 - 1.0)*sin(2.0*MATH_PI*real(i)/1024.0)), 16);
    end loop;
    return ret;
end function fill_sin_rom;

constant sin_rom : rom_t := fill_sin_rom;
```

This code would be in a package for an architecture declaration sections. It requires `use ieee.math_real.all` and `use ieee.numeric_std.all` to work. The advantage of this solution is that it also works in simulation, while the attribute would not.